# How to solve "Find k so that the matrices are ..."

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I always get very stuck in attempting to do these variety of questions.

Say we have another matrix `A`:
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & -1 & -4\\ 
k & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

And say we have a example matrix `B`:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & -2\\ 
1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

I believe there are a variety of questions one can ask regarding the matrix, such as:

Find k so that:

- A has the same image as a matrix B
- A has the same kernel as a matrix B
- A is invertible
- A has infinite solutions

And a ton more variation of the same type of question. In a general procedural way, how would you guys approach the problem? Thank you!

If anyone's interested in my (probably very inefficient) way of thinking about the problem, I was thinking of row reducing the matrix and if the question is about image, then I would take the basis of matrix B's image and then check if the span of any of the combinations of matrix A's columns after the rref would be similar. The difficult part with my approach is that if the first two columns of the matrix A do not span the same subspace as matrix B's rref, then I'd have to check which ones were not orthogonal with each basis in B and try to reproduce that. (Sorry if I butchered the notation/explanation, will do further edits to make it clearer if not clear enough)

Comment: You have to determine the image and kernel depending on $k$. For the third question calculate the determinant. What is finally meant by infinite solutions?

Comment: @Fakemistake thank you for replying. Could you elaborate on determining the first statement? And for the determinant part, we didn't learn determinants yet so far in the class(I'm not sure why they teach in this order), so I'm not sure if they want us to do that, or to find that the rref procedure would not work for a given k. For infinite solutions, I meant given an answer, and we rref the matrix A, we see that, say the last row is `0 0 0 | 0` after rref, which is 0 = 0, which is infinite solutions.

Comment: You can answer the first and second question only for a given matrix $B$.

Comment: @Fakemistake I understand - I'll post an example matrix B if that would help at all?

Comment: As a last hint, $A$ is invertible iff it has rank 3 or trivial kernel. Use gaussian elimination for this part.

Comment: @Fakemistake Ah, I see. That makes sense for the invertible portion. Thank you! :)